# OmniAuth RailsCast (episode 235) issue with Remind Me (episode 274)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railscasts

I followed Ryan Bates'/RailsCasts tutorial for cookies login and remind me functionality in an application I am building.

[reference: [http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password?view=comments]](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password?view=comments)

I wanted to introduce his OmniAuth functionality for the same application.

[reference: [http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1]](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1)

I'm not using devise. I am correctly loading the Twitter app page, the error occurs when redirecting back to my application. I have the callback URL correctly set within Twitter.

I am getting an `undefined method "authentications" for nil:NilClass` error with OmniAuth and my authentications_controller. Specifically my console reads:

`NoMethodError (undefined method authentications for nil:NilClass):app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:9:in create'.`

Here is the Authentications Controller code:

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    authentications = Authentication.all
  end

  def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    current_user.authentications.create(:provider => auth['provider'], :uid => auth['uid'])
    flash[:notice] = "Authentication was successful."
    redirect_to authentications_url
  end
```

Here is the current_user helper method in my Applications Controller.

```
private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
  end
  helper_method :current_user
```

User has many authentications.
Authentications belong to user.

I'd like to enable OmniAuth to work with Twitter so users can login with their Twitter account by avoiding the error I am receiving while maintaining my current_user code

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're not taking into account the case where the user is not logged in.
What you're doing in your `create` action is associating the user's account on your site to his account on Twitter.

You can't use `current_user` without making sure that the user is logged in. Otherwise it will return `nil`, and that's why it's saying `undefined method authentications for nil:NilClass`.

Take a look at the next railscast that goes into more details: http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2